# Using sys.exit() within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to use `sys.exit()` within a function `my_func()`, how do I use it?

```
def my_func():

    try:
        some_method()
    except:
        print('Error')
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    my_func()
```

Comment: What's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import sys` before you can use it. Just add it to the top of your script:

```
import sys

def my_func():
    try:
        some_method()
    except:
        print('Error')
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_func()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three programming issues.  Besides the missing `import sys`, you flag an error but simply call `sys.exit()` which exits with a zero indicating success to the invoker -- it needs to exit non-zero to indicate error.  Finally you print the error message to `sys.stdout` when it really should go to `sys.stderr`.  A rework of your code:

```
import sys

def my_func():

    try:
        some_method()
    except:
        print('Error', file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    my_func()
```

Fortunately, Python allows us to combine these last two issues by instead doing:

```
import sys

def my_func():

    try:
        some_method()
    except:
        sys.exit('Error')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    my_func()
```

This will exit non-zero and print the message to `sys.stderr`.